# Add identifier to visual force page

Tags: apex, soql, apexpage

We need to filter some specific visual force pages from the ORG.

Let's say we have 1000 visual force pages in total and there are 100 visual force pages related to the admin.

Now, we have to have a query the 100 admin pages only `SELECT ID, NAME, MasterLabel FROM APEXPAGE WHERE ~~`.

If we have to keep away from modifying `name`, `master label`, `description` field. How could we use a query for filter the admin pages?

Any fields could we leverage to filter them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add custom fields into Apex Page object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/203564/how-to-add-custom-fields-into-apex-page-object)

Comment: How is this question different than your last question on this subject?

Comment: @battery.cord It's phrased differently (i.e. took a step back from the original X-Y problem). That said, your answer is still applicable. If anything, I'd suggest answering *this* question and then closing the other as duplicate.

Comment: I think your answer covers the question quite well. I'm out of close votes for the day, but I retracted my vote on this question to open it up for other reviewers to take action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One technique I've used in the past is to put some sort of unique identifier in the source code, which I would then identify via SOSL. Here's a simple implementation:

```
ApexPage[] adminPages = [FIND 'AdminPage' RETURNING ApexPage(Name)][0];
```

In your Visualforce, just add the following code:

```
<!-- AdminPage -->
```

It won't show on the page, but it'll appear in the SOSL results.

---

You could create a Permission Set, then query for the values in the Permission Set.

```
ApexPage[] pages = [SELECT Name FROM ApexPage WHERE Id IN (SELECT SetupEntityId FROM SetupEntityAccess WHERE Parent.Name = 'AdminPages'];
```

---

You could create a Custom Setting or Custom Metadata and populate the values in the list.